# Cuda 10.2 not recognised on Pip installed Pytorch 1.7.1

Tags: pytorch

`Pip` installing Pytorch 1.7.1 [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) on Gtx1660(latest drivers installed) doesn't recognise the installed Cuda toolkit 10.2 on my machine(Windows10).
As this is a personal project, I don't wish to use Anaconda.
How to resolve this?

#INSTALLATION (10.2 CUDA SUPPORT)

```
pip install torch===1.7.1 torchvision===0.8.2 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

#CODE

```
import torch 
device = torch.device("cuda")
# device = torch.device("cuda:0") #ALSO NOT WORKING
cuda_available = torch.cuda.is_available()
cuda_init = torch.cuda.is_initialized()
print(f'device_current = {device},cuda_available = {cuda_available} and cuda_init = {cuda_init}\n')

torch.cuda.init()
print(f'device_current = {device} and cuda_init = {cuda_init}')
```

#TERMINAL

```
device_current = cuda:0,cuda_available = False and cuda_init = False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Script\Ai\Pytorch\mod_test\test1.py", line 8, in <module>
    torch.cuda.init()
  File "C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 137, in init
    _lazy_init()
  File "C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 166, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Comment: "Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled" sounds like a pretty simple problem to me

Comment: Yet *`pip install torch===1.7.1 torchvision===0.8.2 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`* **is the command** given on [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) for a pip install of PyTorch 1.71 w/ CUDA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but here is what I found while searching on their package registry.

For a PyTorch *1.7.1* `pip` install. The instructions on [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) are:

```
## cu101
pip install torch==1.7.1+cu101 torchvision==0.8.2+cu101 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

## cu110
pip install torch===1.7.1+cu110 torchvision===0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Yet the command for CUDA *10.2* support is:

```
## cu102
pip install torch===1.7.1 torchvision===0.8.2 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

This seems off because the CUDA version is not stated anywhere in the command. Yet `download.pytorch.org` provides support for this particular PyTorch version with `cu92`, `cu101`, `cu102`, and `cu110`.

---

You can either use:

```
pip install torch==1.7.0 torchvision==0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch_stable.html
```

or try this instead from the main Torch stable directory:

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cu102 torchvision==0.8.2+cu102 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with multiple versions of pytorch 1.7.1 for cuda 10.2 while having a driver installed with cuda 10.2.

What eventually worked for me was installing pytorch 1.7.1 for cuda 10.1 if that would be a viable option for you?

```
python -m pip install torch==1.7.1+cu101 torchvision==0.8.2+cu101 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

If you would need pytorch 1.7.1 for cuda 10.2 you could try.

```
python -m pip install torch==1.7.1+cu102 torchvision==0.8.2+cu102 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```